# Word for "distance in time"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, translation, time

I need the correct English word for the German expression *(zeitlicher) Abstand*. *Abstand* means "distance", and *zeitlich* means "in time".

> The "distance" between building maintenance dates is about ten days.

Would "lag/spacing" be correct, as Langenscheidt translates it? I doubt it.

My guess would be "interval", but it sounds a bit too mathematical to me.

Comment: Related: [Is there a single word for a “unit of time”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23239/is-there-a-single-word-for-a-unit-of-time)

Comment: I have made your third line an example sentence, because it was almost one, and because it made your question easier to parse. Feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: You might consider rephrasing it. "Building maintenance dates occur about every ten days."  Otherwise, I think *interval* is pretty common and not as mathematical as you might think.

Comment: It's not a sentence, it's a column title in a table.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When referring to 'distance in time', the best word is:

> **Interval**

There is also:

> Period
>   Spell

Comment: +1, and you can reassure OP that interval is not strictly technical ("interval between contractions")

Comment: It should be noted that "interval" to me suggest some kind of recurrence. That's fine for my use case, but it's not perfect in the sense that "distance" does not necessarily imply recurrence. "time span" would be a term that fits as a better general translation.

Answer (score 14):

duration or period

> The duration between building maintenance dates is about ten days.

or

> The period between building maintenance dates is about ten days.

Alternatives include:

- time
- time span
- interval
- term
- spell
- interim
- tide
- space
- stretch
- spread
- gap
- interlude
- opening
- pause

Comment: I like time span, because it's the only reasonable alternative that doesn't imply some kind of recurrence.

Comment: @Quandary "Duration" doesn't imply recurrence either.

Answer (score 8):

Wouldn't time do in this case?

As in `time between building maintenance dates is about ten days.`

Update: If it is a column title and not a sentence as the OP mentioned in the comments, either Interval or Time Interval would be a better choice.

Answer (score 7):

"[timespan](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/timespan)" ?

Comment: Give yourself -1 if you're a programmer, @tim_hutton :)

Comment: @JeffSahol: I am a programmer but I don't know what you mean. :(

Comment: Ah, should have said .NET developer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx