# What is this time describing noun called?

Tags: nouns, time

A noun for when something happened is *occasion*. A noun for how long something took is *duration*.

But how would you describe an event that happened at a certain time after an occasion?

Example:

1. The movie **started** 7:15 pm on Sunday 15/3.
2. The **duration** of the movie was one hour 35 minues.
3. Three minutes **into the movie** a guy showed up.
4. 45 minutes **into the movie** I left the cinema.

Is there a more general noun to describe *into the movie*?

Comment: *Started* is not a noun; *into the movie* is not a noun or noun phrase. I would say "Three minutes after the movie started," because you need some reference point to measure the three minutes from.

Comment: During for more general, but not a noun, but being more general it doesn't work with a time. The more specific *into the* is perfect. Why do you need a noun, when you didn't use the noun *starting time* for the start?
There isn't really a relationship between the leaving and the movie that is covered by 45minutes; that covers the relationship between the leaving and the starting time.

Comment: I wonder whether the question on [distance in time](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/word-for-distance-in-time) deals with this?

Comment: Yes... `after`. Of course.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Nice list!

Comment: Well, I might have mixed up nouns with other classes of words. After is certainly not a noun.

Comment: "After the movie started" works, and is perhaps a shade more formal, but I still prefer "into the movie" as more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically all time references in English are metaphoric. There are surprisingly few words that only refer to time: *during, duration, durable, when, then, now, future, past*. Most of the rest come from two major [Metaphor Themes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf):

1. [***Time*** Is **Money**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf)
   *spend a year, lose an hour, save ten minutes, cost me an hour, not worth the time*
2. [***Time*** Is **Space**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf)
   *before/after (fore/aft),  behind you/ahead of you, the months ahead/the following months*

The use of *into the movie* (or *into the meal, into the trip*, etc. -- any noun designating an event with duration can be used here) is an example of the Motion in Space variant.

The experiencer of duration is metaphorically moving through Time, which is represented as 3-dimensional space. Hence *through* and *into* are appropriate prepositions to refer to the durational constituents -- cohesive cognitive events like watching a movie or hearing a speech or doing a morning's work or conducting a career -- through is appropriate for an undifferentiated event (*throughout my life in Denver*), and in(to) for a timed event a specified "length" of time from the beginning. [Metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf) are  unavoidable in language.

I.e, just as one says, *50 miles into the trip*, one may say *50 minutes into the movie*.